# How can i read printer information for a DNP DS620 printer found in the windows printer driver menu in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, printing, driver

I have a DNP DS620 photo printer of which I need to periodically check the status (Remaining Prints and Status Message such as OK or Paper Jam). The windows printer settings menu shows that information as shown in the attached screenshot.

[image]

There is also a DNP tool that does already query said information: http://dnpphoto.com/Portals/0/Resources/PrinterInfo_1.2.1.1.zip

However, this tool displays a warning on startup not to use it while printing, which might not be optimal for automatic background use. Moreover, there is no interface to this application anyway.

I am thankful for any ideas on how to approach this problem.

Comment: Well for printer issues such as paper jam most printer trigger and event log which you can easily find and read

Comment: Interesting approach, however for me, the Hardware Events section in the Windows Events viewer stays empty no matter what happens to the printer.

Comment: @fwinterl Do you know how to get the information in c#? I would like to build an app in shell or python to get this information for my DS620.

Comment: After further research I found out that the `PrinterInfo_1.2.1.1` tool mentioned above ships with a library `CspStat.dll` that can be used by other applications as well. For example:

`[DllImport("CspStat.dll")] private static extern int GetMediaCounter(int portno);`
gives you a method to query the remaining prints for a printer.

However, I must warn you that the printer might freeze if these requests are made at the wrong time, e.g. while printing (not always, but it happens). Moreover, I am also not sure about licensing aspects regarding this dll.